# Facebook fan page empty for non-connected users

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I manage many Facebook pages.
On some of them, everybody can the the status updates.
On others, only connected members can see them, others can't see anything.
I checked the page's parametters and i can't figure out what the hell is different between them. Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that Facebook shows only really recent page updates to non-connected user. Having no recent updates on most of my pages made me think it wasn't displaying anything at all.